# Matlab: Inequality in If statement results in error

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I apologize in advance, I'm sure the answer to this question is quite trivial, unfortunately I am just not sure what is going on.

I am trying to run the following code

```
a(1) = -2;
b(1) = 2;
c(1) = 0;


for i = 1:15

  if cubicPoly(a(i))*cubicPoly(c(i)) < 0
    a(i+1) = a(i);
    b(i+1) = c(i);

  else
    a(i+1) = c(i);
    b(i+1) = b(i);

  end

end
```

but when I do I receive the error message

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Assignment2 (line 31)
if cubicPoly(a(i))*cubicPoly(c(i)) < 0
```

If I evaluate my cubic polynomial function cubicPoly normally, everything works just fine.  But inside the for/if loop when evaluated at the sequences a(i) and c(i) it results in an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Umm no I don't believe so. The code you see there is all there is aside from the separately defined function. Idk maybe I created my function incorrectly or something? I suppose maybe I should post my code for cubicPoly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you ever add more elements to `c`; when `i = 2`, you're trying to access `c(2)` in `if cubicPoly(a(i))*cubicPoly(c(i)) < 0`, which takes you out of bounds.

You might want to include something like `c(i+1) = ...` if you intend to add elements to `c` while looping.

Comment: Yes I think that is it.  Thank you. I  realized I need c(i+1) = (a(i)+b(i))/2. I knew I was going to feel silly after finding out what I as doing wrong.